# identify variant type

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

I am confusing the following problem by identifying the a specific type within  `boost::variant` and pass it as member function argument within a class object. Consider the following code

```
typedef boost::variant<int, string, double> Variant;

class test{ 

  void func1 (Variant V); 
  void func2 (string s); 
  void func3 ();


}; 


test::func1(Variant V){
    // How can I identify the type of V inside the body of this function? 
Or how can I call the apply_visitor inside this function.
  /*
  if(v.type() == string) 
    func2(); 
  else if(v.type() == double) 
    funct3(); 
  */
}
int test::func2(){ cout << "func3" << endl;}
int test::func3(){ cout << "func4" << endl;}
...

int main ()
{
  test t;
      Variant V = 3;
      t.func1(V); 
      V = "hello"; 
      t.func1(V);

}
```

I thought sure about implementing a visitation class/structure (apply_visitor ) within class test. However I got stuck by calling a outer member function namely func3(string s) from the overloaded operator implemented in the visitor class.

Comment: I really can't understand clearly what you want here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The visitor pattern reification will make the compiler do the type-checking for you.  All you need to do is tell the compiler *what* to do when a `string` is in the `Variant`:

(check out the example at
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html)

```
struct my_dispatcher : public boost::static_visitor<> {

    test* t;
    my_dispatcher(test* t): t(t) {}

    void operator()( string s ) { t.func3(s); }
    void operator()( double d ) { t.func4(d); }
    //... for each supported type
};
```

and use `boost::apply_visitor` to choose the correct function:

```
int main ()
{
  test t;
  my_dispatcher dispatcher(&t);

  Variant V = 3;
  boost::apply_visitor( dispatcher, v );

  V = "hello"; 
  boost::apply_visitor( dispatcher, v );    
}
```

The `my_dispatcher(&t)` will create an object of your static_visitor implementation, that will be used by the `apply_visitor` magic.

Hope that's what your were looking fore, since your question wasn't really clear.

Note: alternatively, you derive your `test` from `static_visitor`.

Comment: Sure, I knew this solution. However, it missed the important part that I asked about. In particular, all functions and member variables shall be  implemented within the class test. The Issue is when you create a new intance from the class test within my_sispatcher, you do not have access any more on the intance form which you want actully the function func3(string s)  to be executed... any Idea...

Comment: @sam: Replace `test t` with a pointer to a shared `test` object.

Comment: @Mankarse: How to set a pointer to a shared test object within the my_dispatcher since the test object at that time is still not declared. How could I pass it as an argument to my_dispatcher. Does it make any sense?

Comment: Pass `this` (the `test` object) to the constructor of `my_dispatcher` when you construct the dispatcher in `func1`.